# Redirect Old Product to new (Opencart) (HTACCESS)

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

I want to redirect my old product ID to a new one.

eg:
From: h*tp://www.mysite.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=50
to: h*tp://www.mysite.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=80

OR

From: h*tp://www.mysite.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=63_64_83&product_id=163
To: h*tp://www.mysite.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=63_64_83&product_id=175

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|.*?&)product_id=50(&.*|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1product_id=80%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|.*?&)product_id=163(&.*|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1product_id=175%2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also set up a nice switch control in your seo_url controller that would use the redirect method of the Controller class to do this in a more native way.

Open:

`catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php`

Just before:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['route'])):
    return $this->forward($this->request->get['route']);
endif;
```

Add:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])):
    switch ($this->request->get['product_id']):
        case 50:
            $this->request->get['product_id'] = 80;
            $redirect = true;
            break;
        case 163:
            $this->request->get['product_id'] = 175;
            $redirect = true;
            break;
    endswitch;
endif;

if (isset($this->request->get['route']) && $redirect):
    $this->redirect($this->request->get['route'], 301);
endif;
```

Didn't test specifically, but I have something similar to change some urls.